# OpenLayers 6.5.0: Features disappear when zooming in

Tags: openlayers-6

When zooming in, all features disappear. The features are on either side of the antimeridian. In order to be able to use modify interaction, the geographical lengths of some features exceed the value of 180 degrees.

Any help is welcome!

```js
var coords = [
  [32100000, -7900000],
  [28900000, -9700000],
  [26300000, -10000000],
  [23800000, -9300000],
  [20400000, -6500000]
];

var osmLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.OSM()
});

var featuresLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector()
});

var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [osmLayer, featuresLayer],
  target: document.getElementById("map")
});

var s = featuresLayer.getSource();
for (var i = 0; i < coords.length; i++) {
  s.addFeature(new ol.Feature({
    geometry: new ol.geom.Point(coords[i])
  }));
}

map.setView(new ol.View({
  center: coords[parseInt(coords.length / 2)],
  zoom: 3,
  maxZoom: 18,
  minZoom: 3
}));
```

```css
html,
      body,
      .map {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.5.0/css/ol.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.5.0/build/ol.js"></script>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
```

Comment: Use `new ol.source.Vector({wrapX: false})` if your coordinates exceed the normal world

Comment: @Mike: Thank you very much! I played around with the wrapX property of the source, but was a little bit misled by the documentation. The default value for ol.source is "false" while - indeed - the default value for ol.source.Vector is "true". I've overlooked. My mistake!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per @Mike's comment, use `new ol.source.Vector({wrapX: false})` if your coordinates exceed the normal world

```js
var featuresLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector({wrapX: false})
});
```

**updated code snippet:**

```js
var coords = [
  [32100000, -7900000],
  [28900000, -9700000],
  [26300000, -10000000],
  [23800000, -9300000],
  [20400000, -6500000]
];

var osmLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.OSM()
});

var featuresLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector({wrapX: false})
});

var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [osmLayer, featuresLayer],
  target: document.getElementById("map")
});

var s = featuresLayer.getSource();
for (var i = 0; i < coords.length; i++) {
  s.addFeature(new ol.Feature({
    geometry: new ol.geom.Point(coords[i])
  }));
}

map.setView(new ol.View({
  center: coords[parseInt(coords.length / 2)],
  zoom: 3,
  maxZoom: 18,
  minZoom: 3
}));
```

```css
html,
      body,
      .map {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.5.0/css/ol.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.5.0/build/ol.js"></script>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
```